# How to open a page in new tab when user clicks ctrl key + link button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code which opens new page in different tab.

```
        protected void facebook_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            myurl = "http://www.facebook.com";
            string newWin = "window.open('" + myurl + "');";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
        }
```

But when i press ctrl key from key board and click link button then new tab is opened but in URL

> javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton2','') displays. and page is empty.

but i want to display facebook.com in new tab.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a hyperlink?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you......In Page_Load event just add code

```
facebook.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('http://www.facebook.com','List','width=600,height=500,status,resizable');return false;");
```

or just add facebook.Attributes.Add("onclick","window.open('http://www.facebook.com');");

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using server side control , that requires postback to get the target url or script.

Make anchor tag or any client side control , other code seems fine.